# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /path/time/processing/time/viewpunlist.php on line 54

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

I am trying to get this php code to run. I have made it output the table, however, I am getting this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /path/time/processing/time/viewpunlist.php on line 54

I have been able to use the $row to get the values of it before and even reassigned it later to make sure that it wasn't only executing in WHILE. I have no clue what is going on there. Line 54 is the line:

```
foreach ( $row as $each)
```

Here is the file that I am using it in. Any help is appreciated on

a) how to make this file better and
  b) getting the whole foreach statement working.

Thank you in advance!

```
<head>
    <title>View My Punches</title>
    <body bgcolor="#9966FF">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://example.com/time/favicon.ico"/>
</head>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_HOST', 'host');


$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if ($link->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Could not connect: ' .connect_error());
}
$userid_value = $_POST['userid'];
$table = "tc_".$userid_value;
$checkusersql = "SELECT * FROM tc_users WHERE userid = '$userid_value'";
$usercheck = $link->query($checkusersql);
$punchessql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id";
$result = $link->query($punchessql);
$unixtime = time() + 60*60;
$time_value = date("h:i:s A", $unixtime);
$date_value = date("m/d/Y", $unixtime);
if ($usercheck->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, " . $userid_value . " is not a valid user ID. Please try again.";
}else {
    echo "Punch Report for " . $userid_value . "      |       Generated at " . $time_value . " on " . $date_value;
    echo "<p></p>";
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        echo "<p></p>";
        echo "No punches were found for " . $userid_value . ".";
    }else{
        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr><th>Punch ID</th><th>Time</th><th>Punch Type</th><th>Group</th><th>Department</th><th>Notes</th></tr>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['time'] . "</td><td>" . $row['punchtype'] . "</td><td>" . $row['groupname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dept'] . "</td><td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

}
$differs = array();
$inout = array();
$inarray = array();
$outarray = array();
$current = array('in'=>$inarray,'out'=>$outarray,'length'=>'');
foreach ( $row as $each)
{
    if ( $each['punchtype'] == 'in' )
    {
        if ( empty($current['in']) )
        {  $current['in'] = $each;  }
    }
    else if ( $each['punchtype'] == 'out' )
    {
        if ( empty($current['out']) )
        {  $current['out'] = $each;  }
    }

    if (( !empty($current['in']) && !empty($current['out'])))
    {
        $in = new DateTime($current['in']);
        $out = new DateTime($current['out']);
        $current['length'] = $in->diff($out);
        $inout[] = $current; 
        $stamp = $inout['length'];
        $stampformat = $stamp->format('%s');
        $stampint = intval($stampformat);
        $stampintval = $stampint/3600;
        echo $stampintval;
  }
}

?>
&nbsp
&nbsp
<form method="GET" action="http://example.com/time/panel.php">
<input type="submit" value="Go Home">
</form>
```

Comment: *"a) how to make this file better"* - That is best suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why do you have error reporting OFF `ini_set('display_errors', 0)`? That should be a `1`.

Comment: sounds good. I will post there too.

Comment: I did change it to 1 after I posted. That is how I got the error message.

Comment: `$row` is only accessible within that `while()` loop of yours. Simply add this in that loop `$rows[] = $row;` and then `foreach($rows as $each) {....code`

Comment: OK. That fixed that error but produced another one: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given' in /path/time/processing/time/viewpunlist.php:73 Stack trace: #0 /path/time/processing/time/viewpunlist.php(73): DateTime->__construct(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /path/time/processing/time/viewpunlist.php on line 73

Comment: @AdamMiller so fix it..? The error is telling you exactly whats wrong. You're parsing an array to the function when it expects a string.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is literally the file copy and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the argument passed through foreach is an array.

This can be done by using the function `is_array()`

```
if (is_array($variable)) {
  foreach ($variable as $item) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, which I do a lot, it seems to me that you've already iterated through your SQL results here,

```
if ($usercheck->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, " . $userid_value . " is not a valid user ID. Please try again.";
}else {
    echo "Punch Report for " . $userid_value . "      |       Generated at " . $time_value . " on " . $date_value;
    echo "<p></p>";
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        echo "<p></p>";
        echo "No punches were found for " . $userid_value . ".";
    }else{
        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr><th>Punch ID</th><th>Time</th><th>Punch Type</th><th>Group</th><th>Department</th><th>Notes</th></tr>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['time'] . "</td><td>" . $row['punchtype'] . "</td><td>" . $row['groupname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dept'] . "</td><td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

}
```

which means that the data is no longer available because you are not using a prepared statement in order to reuse it. You should be able to run another query for the foreach.

```
$punchessql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id";
$result = $link->query($punchessql);
$row = $result->fetch_array();
foreach ( $row as $each) {
//your existing code.
}
```